# Click event for programatically generated XAML buttons

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm programatically generating a table where Text2 the columns are a button:

```
for (int i = 0; i < workPackages.Length; i++)
{
    //Define new Row to add
    RowDef = new RowDefinition();
    RowDef.Height = new GridLength(60);

    //Add row definition to Grid
    WorkPackageResults.RowDefinitions.Add(RowDef);

    //Define the control that will be added to new row
    Text1 = new TextBlock();
    Text1.Text = workPackages[i].EWPStatus;
    Text1.Width = 100;
    Text1.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

    Text2 = new Button();
    Text2.Content = workPackages[i].EWPCode;
    Text2.Width = 300;

    Text3 = new TextBlock();
    Text3.Text = workPackages[i].Description;
    Text3.Width = 500;
    Text3.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

    Text4 = new TextBlock();
    Text4.Text = workPackages[i].ForeBadge;
    Text4.Width = 100;
    Text4.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

    //create stackpanel and define which row to add the stackpanel to
    StackP = new StackPanel();
    StackP.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i);
    StackP.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
    StackP.Margin = new Thickness(50, 0, 0, 0);

    //add your control to the stackpanel
    StackP.Children.Add(Text1);
    StackP.Children.Add(Text2);
    StackP.Children.Add(Text3);
    StackP.Children.Add(Text4);

    //add the stackpanel to the grid
    WorkPackageResults.Children.Add(StackP);
}
```

[image]

How do I programatically add a click event? And when that click event is executed how do I know which button it came from?

Comment: Attach commands to your buttons and bind to the commands... otherwise add click handlers.  It shouldn't be any different to how you would normally do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event handler to Text2.Click that will pass the sender as a parameter, that's how you know which one was clicked.